# Referencing worksheets in excel spreadsheet by index rather than name in r

Tags: r

Im trying to use XLconnect in order to import worksheets as my datasource

If I use the code below I get the subsequent error

```
 library(XLConnect)
 wk = loadWorkbook("/Users/sebastianzeki/Desktop/SequencingScripts/bedtools/bedtools2-master/CohortComparisons/PanCancerCommonSCNAs.xlsx")
amp_genesAll_cancer = readWorksheet(wk, sheet="amp_genes.All_cancer.txt", header=TRUE)
Error: IllegalArgumentException (Java): Sheet index (-1) is out of range (0..25)
```

One work around would be to convert the names to numbers of the worksheets but I still need to have control over how each one is imported rather than importing all into one dataframe. Not sure how to do this though

Comment: The help file (`?XLConnect::readWorksheet`) seems to indicate that you *can* use indexes of worksheets: `sheet: 
The name or index of the worksheet to read from`

Comment: Have you tried to give "getSheets(wk)" a shot to see the names of the available worksheets ... and to avoid mistyping ... sometimes the names getSheets returns are different from the ones you would expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `wk =` code runs correctly, and you see a 'formal class workbook' object appear, you have likely misspelled your sheet name. The index -1 means that your string given as the title does not match.

To use indexes, use:

```
amp_genesAll_cancer = readWorksheet(wk, sheet=1, header=TRUE)
```

With 1 being the sheet number

Comment: in combination with nrussell the problem was typos. Running getSheets(wk) showed this to be the case. Cheers